# Is it possible to run Hive and Pig in the same node?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, cluster-computing

I'm new to Hadoop, but I have been trying to create a single-node cluster for a college project. My goal is to perform mapreduce jobs into the same data but while using different Hadoop-based software, these being Hive and Pig. 
So, I would like to know if I could install and run both Hive and Pig in the same node? What about in the same cluster, suppousing it has more than 10 nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the college project, it ok to create single-node cluster(make sure hadoop is installed in Pseudo-distributed mode-  master, slave in same machine ).

You can install hive and pig on same node, as they both are just CLIs/Shells to launch MR jobs on hadoop-pseudo cluster.

launch both as follows in different terminals:

HIVE  > $ hive

PIG : > $ pig -x mapreduce  //hadoop-mode

Actually Pig grunt or hive shell are just interfaces to give jobs to cluster (Say 1 or 10 node cluster), in such case pig or hive shell acts just like a Client.So installing on any node not matters.